# Editing/Saving Files live on unix server

Tags: unix, ftp

I can connect remotely to my unix server via SSH, both ftp and shell mode using port 22. However I am not able to do so in Visual Studio. I want to be able to edit files live in a GUI interface.

Any solutions for this?

Thanks!

Comment: So complain to Microsoft to add this feature, because it's their closed-source proprietary product (so you can't add the feature yourself) and you paid for it (which gives you at least moral right) to fill in a feature request.

Comment: Wait, you want to run a X-server in visual studio? Has it ever offered that functionality, or even anything remotely like it?

Comment: @Fake: I think he meant editing over SFTP, some text editors are capable of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Visual Studio running on a Windows Pc to be able to open files directly, you will have to use some kind of file server technology. There are two options, either you install samba on the unix box to make it work like a windows server or install NFS on the unix and an NFS client on Windows.

If you have firewall restrictions only allowing ssh on port 22 you should be able to set up a port forwarding system for at least samba, but it is definitely a non-trivial setup.

Comment: Windows 7 (at least some releases) already includes a NFS client as optional feature. I myself prefer Samba, it at least has authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows/). I haven't used it myself, but it emulates the remote host as an extra drive.

Searching around for a "sshfs for windows" I also came across [dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/). It seems to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Cygwin](http://x.cygwin.com/) or [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) which would run X on your windows computer. Then you can run any gui you can find on the linux computer over the ssh by executing it from the command line. It's similar to adding the -X flag to an ssh command between linux boxes. Unfortunately this wouldn't give you the ability to run Visual Studio but you can run gedit, or any IDE that you want that runs native on Linux.